# What goes underneath of monkey patch in Python

Tags: python

I'm a bit confused and trying to understand what goes underneath in the hope that I would understand Monkey Patch better.

I've read [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) and I understand that I have to patch from where you use the module. But in the documentation.

```
a.py
    -> Defines SomeClass

b.py
    -> from a import SomeClass
    -> some_function instantiates SomeClass
```

If I do this `from a import SomeClass`

Then I have to patch like this.

`@patch('b.SomeClass')`

However, why if I import the module like this.

`import a`

I instead have to use the patch like this.

`@patch('a.SomeClass')`

I only understand how to use the patch but I don't understand why is this the case? Is it the way Python import module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to intercept, and modify, the reference that will be used by functions whose behavior you want to affect. Initially, `a.SomeClass` and `b.SomeClass` point to the same object; but the patch will replace one of these references with something else.

In the documentation, the example is that you want to modify the `SomeClass` that is seen and used by `some_function`. So what matters is how `some_function()` refers to `SomeClass`:

1. If `some_function` contains a reference to plain `SomeClass`, it will be resolved to a variable in its own module: `b` in this example (and incidentally `b` created this variable by importing it). Hence `b.SomeClass` is what needs to be patched.
2. If `some_function` explicitly refers to `a.SomeClass`, then that's the reference that needs to be patched.

Suppose module `b.py` contains *both* of these lines:

```
import a
from a import SomeClass
```

Which reference should be patched? Why, the one that is used by `some_function`! What matters is not how it's imported into `b`, but how it's accessed by the code that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

This all has to do with namespaces.

Inside of `b.py`, when the command `from a import SomeClass` executes, `SomeClass` is added to the *namespace* of module `b`. Thus, you have `b.SomeClass`.

In the other case, when still inside of `b.py` and you execute the command `import a`, all that happens is that the module `b` now has access to the namespace of module `a`. So from a global point of view, the class being used inside of `b` is still `a.SomeClass`.